# Installshield response file not being generated

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I've built an installer using InstallShield 2011. I need to do a silent install so I ran the setup.exe with the -r flag to record the response file. However, the installer doesn't appear to actually generate a file (I've looked in the windows directory for the .iss file - in fact I've looked over my entire hard disk for .iss files)

I'm installing on Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate Edition and running from an elevated command prompt

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas why the file isn't getting generated?

Comment: Are you certain the setup in question is from an InstallScript or InstallScript MSI project? A setup from a Basic MSI project will not record response files.

Comment: Ah - that explains it - thanks. I didn't spot the need for InstallScript. So I have to manually create the response file (I assume response files can still be used)?

Comment: No, MSI projects have no need for response files.  You just author your installer using Public / SecureCustomProperties and standard MSI command line arguments for silent installation.   Response Files are an InstallScript concept from the 1990's.

Comment: Thanks that all makes sense now - silent install now running successfully